# Remote address not showing in php

Tags: php

I want to show remote address in php through global keyword and global variable , also I want to access $user_ip inside function show_ip().

```
<?php
   $user_ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

   function show_ip(){
       global $user_ip;
       echo "Your ip address is".$user_ip;
   }

   show_ip();
?>
```

I should get output of `127.0.0.1` where as I am getting `::1`

Comment: ::1 is the ipv6 equivalent of ipv4 127.0.0.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`::1` is IPv6 equivalent of `127.0.0.1`. Since you are running this on local computer, the browser is able to connect over IPv6 instead of IPv4, therefore surprising you.

Answer (score 0):

`::1` ([IPv6](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6_address#Default_address_selection)) is the "same" as `127.0.0.1` (IPv4). If you get `::1` this indicates that your browser accesses your local webserver using [IPv6](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6).